# Is there anyway to build application with special commit in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I have automated an application using Jenkins. When I push my code to master branch, Jenkins script runs and rebuild the application. This is my current situation.

What I need to do now, When I push with specific commit message only, I need to trigger the Jenkins build. (For an example, Commit message consist of "Build" keywork can only build the application again.)

```
Ex:-
git commit -m "Build | this is demo commit" - should be build the application.
git commit -m "this is demo commit" - should not be rebuild.
```

Am I possible to do that?

Comment: I've found how to ignore certain messages. https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-polling-ignores-commits-with-certain-messages. You can play around to see if there is an option to ignore messages that don't include a string `Build`

Comment: @YuriG. Thank you. I'll check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with a declarative pipeline. Note the condition `when { changelog 'Build |.*'}`

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git (url: 'https://github.com/ycr/sample.git', branch: 'main')
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build') {
            when {  changelog 'Build |.*' }
            steps {
               echo "BUILDING"
            }
        }
    }
}
```